# Use grep command date between specific years

Tags: linux, bash, date, grep

```
grep -E '^[[:digit:]]{4}\.[[:digit:]]{2}\.[[:digit:]]{2}'
```

I need help to type date yyyy.mm.dd that only accept years between 1950 and 2050.

Comment: Before anyone will help you, you need to at least have made an attempt to answer the question, and have a specific problem that can be replicated by others.  See the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Question upgraded!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since grep does not understand math, the solution is a bit tedious:

```
grep -E '^(19[56789][[:digit:]]|20[01234][[:digit:]]|2050)\.[[:digit:]]{2}\.[[:digit:]]{2}'
```

This allows the year field to be any of the following three regexes:

1. `19[56789][[:digit:]]`
2. `20[01234][[:digit:]]`
3. `2050`